# reputation in /users/[ids] different than reputation in /users/[ids]/reputation

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I am using the 2.2 API to display users stats by quarter, but I also want to display reputation changes between any 2 dates.

I use the `/users/[ids]` API to get the summaries. User 2403309 shows a 72 reputation change in the quarter (which matches his profile), but the `/users/2403309/reputation` api shows entries that add up to 68 and it seems to be missing a couple of "accepts"

Any idea as to why this is?

Here's the screenshot of the profile:
[image: This adds up to 72 points]

Now, this is the JSON I get by querying that user since 01.01 until 05.04 (which is two days in the future, because otherwise SO was not including some reputation points, but that is a separate question).

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "on_date": 1399076511,
      "reputation_change": 10,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "answer",
      "post_id": 23416402,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1399076478,
      "reputation_change": 10,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "answer",
      "post_id": 23416787,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398979754,
      "reputation_change": 15,
      "vote_type": "accepts",
      "post_type": "answer",
      "post_id": 23416787,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398977734,
      "reputation_change": 15,
      "vote_type": "accepts",
      "post_type": "answer",
      "post_id": 23416402,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398718062,
      "reputation_change": -2,
      "vote_type": "down_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 23348663,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398712175,
      "reputation_change": 5,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 23348663,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398711479,
      "reputation_change": 5,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 23348269,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398711171,
      "reputation_change": 5,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 17688439,
      "user_id": 2403309
    },
    {
      "on_date": 1398711150,
      "reputation_change": 5,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 17394188,
      "user_id": 2403309
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9940
}
```

Comment: I think this sort of question is better asked on http://stackapps.com/questions

Comment: I'll try to post it there also. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If google brought you here, the reason why the reputation reported via `/user/{ids}/reputation` doesn't match the profile data is that the `reputation` API seems to return more idiosyncratic reputation objects. `reputation-history` on the other hand, is accurate.

Check the accepted answer that @michaelB958 provided to the same post in [the stackapps forum](https://stackapps.com/questions/4670/different-reputation-stats-between-user-ids-and-user-ids-reputation).